# Recursive function: echo works, return doesn't

Tags: php, recursion, return, echo

The function aims at finding an item in a range of arrays, and then returning its key.

Problem is that the function doesn't return anything, whereas it would echo the expected result...
Here is my code:

```
function listArray($tb, $target){
    foreach($tb as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){ // current value is an array to explore
            $_SESSION['group'] = $key; // saving the key in case this array contains the searched item
            listArray($value, $target);
        }else {
            if ($target == $value) { // current value is the matching item
                return $_SESSION['group']; //Trying to return its key
                break; // I'd like to close foreach as I don't need it anymore
                }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, an other little thing: I'm not used to recursive function, and I didn't find any other solution than using a session variable. But there might be a nicer way of doing it, as I don't use this session variable elsewhere...

Comment: What happens when none of the conditions you set are met? i.e. if $value isn't an array but it's also != $target. This might be the source of the problem.

Comment: what's the goal of the function?

Comment: The function aims at finding an item in a range of arrays, and then returning its key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally bypassed the problem by storing my result in a `$_SESSION` variable.

So, no `return` anymore...

```
$_SESSION['item'][$target] = $_SESSION['group'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a `return` before the recurring `listArray` call.

Thank about it ..

```
return;
break;
```

That `break` is never reached (I don't believe you can use `break` to exit a function in php anyway)

The second `return` returns from a recursive call.  Let's say that this was not two separate functions:

```
function foon() {
   barn();
}
function barn() {
   return true;
}
```

`foon` has no return statement.

Comment: I didn't paste my other tries.
One of them was to `return` outside the `foreach`. Is this what you mean ?

Comment: You *could* do that .. you have to store the result of the `listArray` function into a variable, though.  Actually you need to change your function a bit since you don't want the correct `listArray` result to be overwritten if an incorrect value comes later (I think you are trying to do that with the break).

Comment: OK, I stored the result in a variable. But I don't understand where I should return it. It doesn't work at the end of the function... `if (isset($result)){return $result;}`